# change type of IBAN char to string

Tags: haskell

I want to create IBAN, but first step is create BBAN. Leading zeros are added to the numbers. Here is the code:

```
iban :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
iban a b c | ((length a == 4) && (length b <= 6) && (length c <= 10)) = createBBAN a b c
           | otherwise = "Error"

createBBAN x y z | ((length y) <  6) = createBBAN x ("0" ++ y) z
                 | ((length z) < 10) = createBBAN x y ("0" ++ z)
                 | otherwise         = x ++ y ++ z
```

But I would like to have iban like this:

```
iban :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> String
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iban :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> String
iban a b c | and [(length $ show a) == 4,
                  (length $ show b) == 6,
                  (length $ show c) <= 10] = createBBAN a b c
           | otherwise = "Error"

createBBAN x y z | ((length y) <  6) = createBBAN x ("0" ++ y) z
                 | ((length z) < 10) = createBBAN x y ("0" ++ z)
                 | otherwise         = x ++ y ++ z
```

Typecast to string and get the length. You could also just call log base 10 to extract the number of digits.

Brain compiled, hopefully ok.

Answer (score 2):

well.. I didnt do haskell for long. But what's about

```
iban :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> String
iban a b c | ((a < 10000) && (a>8999) && (b < 1000000) && (c < 10000000000)) = createBBAN (show a) (show b) (show c)
           | otherwise = "Error"

createBBAN x y z | ((length y) <  6) = createBBAN x ("0" ++ y) z
                 | ((length z) < 10) = createBBAN x y ("0" ++ z)
                 | otherwise         = x ++ y ++ z
```

of course you could apply show later in createBBAN but I think that wouldn't make that much sense because then you would need to convert multiple times.
 => represent Integer by String via

> show